# Convert to Json format from array values with titles to the laravel view

Tags: json, laravel

This is in my Laravel Controller index Method:

```
if(count($least) == 0)
        {
            $events = DB::table('bookings')
             ->join('events','bookings.event_id','=','events.id')
             ->join(DB::raw('(select S.event_id, sum(S.spaces) as sum_spaces from spots S group by S.event_id) d'), function($join)
             {
                $join->on('bookings.event_id', '=', 'd.event_id');
             })
             ->select('bookings.event_id','events.name', 'd.sum_spaces',
                      DB::raw('COUNT(bookings.event_id) as tb'))
             ->groupBy('bookings.event_id')
             ->get();
        //return $events;

            $occupacy = array();
            $eventname_occupacy = array();

            $least = array();
            foreach($events as $event)
            {
                $occupacy[] = $event->tb / $event->sum_spaces * 100;
                $eventname_occupacy[] = $event->name;

            }   
            $least[0] =  min($occupacy);
            $least[1] =  min($eventname_occupacy);
            }
 }
```

In this method I am getting $least array where first value is going to be percentage and second value is the title of the event. 
I need to add custom Title for both array index while converting to Json format.
I tried lot of things like: Json_encode, response()->json() etc. but cant get the format I need.
This is what I have in an array:

```
[2.7397260273973,"Reflexology Massage"]
```

And this is what I want :

```
{ "least": 
    {  
       "occupacy" : "2.7397..."
       "event_name" : "Reflexology Massage"
    }
}
```

So that I can access in Laravel view as

```
$least->event_name and $least->occupacy
```

Or I dont even mind accessing array values in Laravel like:

```
$array[0]  // Where this is the occupacy
$array[1]  // and this is event name
```

Anyway would work until and unless I have the values I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the names to the values in the array first, then convert to json, like so:

```
$a = [2.7397260273973,"Reflexology Massage"];
$array['least'] = [
    'occupancy' => $a[0],
    'event_name' => $a[1]
];
$array = json_encode($array);
```

`$array` at the end should like you with the json form. So you can access it as an object like so: `$array->least->occupancy`

Or, if you just want to access like this: `$least->occupancy` you can do this:

```
$least = [2.7397260273973,"Reflexology Massage"];
$array = [
    'occupancy' => $least[0],
    'event_name' => $least[1]
];
$least = json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Thank you. Second solution is much better.